# reintun vs. reinmachen

Tags: usage

I heard both words used quite often in spoken German in the meaning of "to put something into something".

Are these two words identical in meaning and interchangeable or are there any differences in their usage?

There isn't much information about these words in dictionaries. As far as I know, *rein-* is short for *hinein-* here but I'm only interested in the usage of the colloquial *rein-* forms. I could only find this in Duden:

> **[reintun](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/reintun)**
>   **Bedeutung:**
>   in etwas tun, hineinbringen, -legen, -setzen, -stellen usw.
>
> **[reinmachen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/reinmachen_treffen_einlochen)**
>   **Bedeutungen und Beispiele**
>   1.in etwas hineinlegen, -stellen, -setzen
>   **Gebrauch**
>   salopp
>   **Beispiel**
>   *einen neuen Akku ins Smartphone reinmachen*

For example, can I use either of the words in the following sentences?

> *Mein Nagellack ist eingetrocknet. Das ist schade, da muss ich Nagellack-Entferner **reinmachen** / **reintun**.*
>   *Also hier ist einmal so ein Unterstellplatz, da kann man so Sachen **reinmachen** / **reintun**.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Tun* and *machen* are totally interchangable in that context. There are however regional differences what word you encounter more often.

Again, the [Atlas der deutschen Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/) helps with word distribution, here in the sense of

> You don't do that!

[image: Verteilung Tun/Machen]

The variations *reintun* and *reinmachen* should mirror that.

Comment: *Das tut man nicht machen.*

Comment: +1 weil ich dank dieser Antwort den wundervollen *"Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache"* endeckt habe.

Comment: In Ergänzung zu @Em1: Man tut nicht tun benutzen.

Comment: Und in Ergänzung zu @OregonGhost: Man tut das nicht mit tun tun.

Answer (score 5):

As the others have said, the difference is very small and it also depends highly on the region. However, I think that *machen* is slightly more "complex" a deed - maybe a bit like "to work it in" while *tun* is really just plain quick putting.

> Ich mache den Akku ins Handy rein.
>
> Mach mal den Code in dein Programm rein und dann guck mal, was passiert.

I would find *tun* a little odd here, as I would find *machen* in the following.

> Ich tu die Butter in den Kühlschrank rein.
>
> Ich tu Sinnestraum ins Badewasser rein.

There is a difference between *machen* and *tun* in that *machen* is productive while *tun* is not (or at least that is not the main focus), and I don't see why this difference wouldn't rub of on the *rein*-versions.

Comment: Ich behaupte, dass deine Einschätzung der "gefühlten Bedeutung" durch die Verwendung von tun/machen in deinem Umfeld geprägt ist.

Comment: @npst: mag sein, allerding ist es d'accord mit dem größten Teil von Deutschland und ich glaube es gibt einige Beispiele, in denen man "tun" nicht mit "machen" ersetzen kann ohne dass jemand, der nicht aus der betreffenden Region kommt, sagt, "neeee", während, die, für die die "andersrumme" Verwendung normal ist, einen Tausch als nicht so falsch empfinden...

Comment: absolut. Gäbe es nicht spezielle Unterschiede wäre wohl eins der Worte über die Zeit verschwunden, spekuliere ich.

Answer (score 2):

to be honest there are way more options besides `reintun` and `reinmachen` like `reinstecken` or `hineintun`.

Let me give you an example with Smartphone and Akku.

```
Einen Akku ins Smartphone einlegen.
Einen Akku ins Smartphone stecken.
Einen Akku ins Smartphone machen.
Einen Akku ins Smartphone hineinstecken.
Einen Akku ins Smartphone reinmachen.
```

But as you said, reinmachen is quiete "salopp" , so try to avoid that.