# Nuancen der regionalen und stilistischen Verteilung von "put-Verben"

Tags: dialect, verb-usage, style, regional

Inspiriert durch die Kommentare [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/60800/1626) würde mich interessieren, wie es mit der regionalen Verteilung von unspezifischen Verben für "setzen/legen/stellen" aussieht, unter Berücksichtigung von Unterschieden in Standard- und Umgangssprache.  Anscheinend ist diese nicht so einheitlich, wie von mir bisher angenommen.

("Unspezifisch" in dem Sinn, dass nur die Bewegung ausgedrückt wird, nicht die Art -- also nicht *schütten*, *schmeißen*, *klemmen*, etc.  Inwieweit der Unterschied *setzen*, *legen* und *stellen* schon darunterfällt, wird sich vielleicht in Antworten zeigen -- aber diese drei sind allgemein genug, um sie hier mitaufzunehmen).

## Aufzählung der Varianten

Konkret ging es um das Beispiel

> Erich gibt den Deckel auf den Topf.

welches als speziell österreichisch/süddeutsch erklärt wurde.  Mir, als Österreicher, kommt daran unbewussterweise gar nichts regional vor, und ich halte den Satz für ziemlich standardnah.  Mein "Gegenvorschlag",

> Erich setzt den Deckel auf den Topf.

kommt mir und auch anderen eher schriftsprachlich vor und ist wohl weniger regional markiert.

Die angebotene Alternative

> Erich legt den Deckel auf den Topf.

würde ich selbst als völlig austauschbar mit *gibt* einschätzen, was scheinbar andere nicht so empfinden (weil ja *geben* regional markiert sei).

Dann gibt es natürlich noch die rein umgangssprachlichen Allerwelts-Ersatzverben

> Erich tut/macht den Deckel auf den Topf.

die ziemlich offensichtlich regional variieren.  In [einer anderen Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8664/reintun-vs-reinmachen) wurde erklärt, dass sich die Verteilung von *reintun/reinmachen* an die von *tun/machen* in *das tut/macht man nicht* anlehnen würde; aber stimmt das auch in diesem Fall?  (Den Hilsverb-Gebrauch *tut den Deckel auf den Topf X-en* wollen wir hier ignorieren.)

### *Setzen* statt *legen*

Da sich der Unterschied *setzen/legen* nach der Form des Objekts richtet, müssten wir auch noch folgende parallelen Beispiele mituntersuchen:

- > Anna gibt den Topf auf den Herd.
- > Anna stellt den Topf auf den Herd.
- > ?Anna legt den Topf auf den Herd.
- > Anna setzt den Topf auf den Herd.
- > Anna tut/macht den Topf auf den Herd.

Wobei ich selbst interessanterweise *legen* akzeptabel finde, wenn man den Topf beliebig positioniert (also nicht notwendigerweise auf seinen Boden stellt):

> Leg den Topf zum Trocknen auf den Herd!

aber nicht in seiner Funktion als Kochtopf:

> *Füll Wasser in den Topf und leg ihn auf den Herd!

## Hypothese

Ich würde folgendes daraus schließen:

- *gibt*: Regional (Ö/Süddeutsch), dort standardsprachlich und universell einsetzbar.
- *legt*/*stellt*: Überall standardsprachlich, aber gebunden nach der Form und Funktion des Objekts
- *setzt*: Überall eher schriftsprachlich/gehoben? Gibt es Beschränkungen?
- *tut/macht*: Regional variierend, überall rein umgangssprachlich

Kann das durch Forschung/Referenzen so belegt werden?  Im Idealfall findet jemand eine schöne Karte wie die aus dem Atlas der deutschen Alltagssprache; geben tut es eine solche dort leider nur für [*das tut/macht man nicht*](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-3/f06d/).

Ansonsten freue ich mich auch über durch Beispiele belegte Widersprüche zur hypothetischen Auflistung oben.  Außerdem könnte ich einfach noch ein Wort übersehen haben.

Comment: Ich denke wie @phipsgabler, es wird in der Küche recht nass werden, wenn ich einen mit Wasser befüllten Topf auf den Herd lege; "stellen" und "legen" können (sollten) m.E. nicht synonym verwendet werden, weil "legen" impliziert, dass ein Gegenstand mit der Seite seiner längsten Ausdehnung auf einem anderen platziert wird. Weshalb ich die Wortfolge "einen Deckel auf den Topf legen" für richtig befinde. - Dagegen impliziert "stellen", dass etwas aufrecht platziert wird. ... ad irgendwo (etw.) "reinmachen" - ähm, in Österreich in der Küche nicht wirklich angebracht ;-)

Comment: Andererseits kann man auch eine Billardkugel wohin legen oder stellen. Da kommt mir irgendwie vor, dass der Unterschied darin besteht, dass _legen_ keine besondere Lage impliziert, _stellen_ dagegen auf eine besondere Positionierung. Das verallgemeinert vermutlich deine Theorie. Ad _in der Küche reinmachen_ -- ein Schelm, wer Böses denkt :D

Comment: Abgesehen davon, dass Kugeln naturgemäß über keine längere Ausdehnung verfügen u. "stellen" für mich voraussetzt, dass etwas dann auch dort stehen bleibt, wohin man es gesetzt hat, würde ich bei einer Spielanleitung die Kugelformation aufstellen (vgl. Schachfiguren), wobei ich die Kugeln in die dreieckige Aufstellhilfe lege, um sie im Dreieck zu platzieren ... ja, ist knifflig. ff.

Comment: ff. - Beim Setzen von Druckwerken werden z.B. üblicherweise die Wörter "stellen" und "legen" für die einzelnen Lettern nicht verwendet (außer man legt ein A zur Seite). Ich denke, dass eine universelle Regel aufzustellen für die Wörter "setzen, legen, stellen" kaum möglich ist, weil die jeweilige Anwendung sprachgeschichtlich in direktem Zusammenhang mit den platzierten Objekten steht. Vielleicht habe ich deshalb auch bisher dazu wenige Referenzen gefunden - sämtliche bisher gefundenen "Regeln" und Beispiele waren ungenau, verwaschen und waren im Handumdrehen leicht zu widerlegen.

Comment: @phipsgabler Weitere Verben: _Kleber auf das Papier streichen / **geben**_,  _Sosse über die Nudeln giessen / **geben**_. Nicht unbedingt typisch süddeutsch / österreichisch, aber _geben_ wird dort häufiger verwendet denke ich.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Davon gibt es natürlich unendlich viele Varianten, aber das wollte ich mit "nicht-speziell" eigentlich ausschließen. Ich werde das expliziter machen.

Comment: @TylwythTag-VIE der _setzen_ / _legen_ / _stellen_-Unterschied wäre auch schone eine eigene Frage wert, wenn es noch keine gibt. Darauf wollte ich mich hier eigentlich nicht fokussieren.

Comment: Da ich diese Frage offenbar inspiriert habe: Als Nordostdeutscher lege ich den Deckel auf den Topf, aber ich stelle den Topf auf den Herd. Ich wäre überrascht, wenn man irgendwo im deutschen Sprachraum den Topf auf den Herd legt. Diese [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=31&year_end=2019&content=legte+den+Deckel+auf%2Cgab+den+Deckel+auf%2Csetzte+den+Deckel+auf&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clegte%20den%20Deckel%20auf%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csetzte%20den%20Deckel%20auf%3B%2Cc0) könnten von Interesse sein.

Comment: @phipsgabler: Deine Hypothese stimmt zumindest für Mitteldeutschland. Den Rest überblicke ich nicht aussagekräftig genug.

Answer (score 3):

Ich bin aus Österreich und habe noch nie einen Österreicher, außer vielleicht Wien, "Er gibt den Topf auf den Herd" sagen gehört. Da, wo ich her bin, würde jeder "tun" verwenden.

"stellen": das hätte bei uns eine konkrete Bedeutung, nämlich wirklich hinstellen / aufstellen / wegstellen und nicht die unkonkrete "machen / tun / geben"-Bedeutung. Auch "legen" ist so: legen kann man Sachen, die man nicht hinstellen kann. Wenn man einen Topf legt, dann liegt er auf der Seite. "Leg den Topf zum Trocknen auf den Herd" würde mich verwirren, weil er da ja auf seiner Unterseite auch stehen kann.

Zumindest mir als Tiroler erscheinen besonders "machen" und "geben" eher als bundesdeutsche Ausrücke, zB "reinmachen" oder "reingeben". Das unkonkrete "put"-Verb ist bei uns eigentlich immer "tun" - eini-, aussi-, ummi-, wecktuan etc.

"Setzen" scheint mir eher im Kontext von "hinsetzen" vorzukommen, für die Bedeutung von "etwas auf etwas (drauf)setzen" würden wir "drauftuan" sagen. Generell scheinen die Wörter, bis auf "tun", ihre konkrete Bedeutung bei uns bewahrt zu haben. "Geben" zum Beispiel hat bei uns meistens die Bedeutung von "jemandem etw. geben".

Auch interessant: bei den Deutschen Studenten ist mir aufgefallen, dass sie für "etwas unternehmen" eher "was machen" sagen würden, die Tiroler tendieren dagegen zu "was tun".

Es gibt hierzu alle mögliche Forschung, die Uni Innsbruck hat mal eine Umfragenserie durchgeführt, wo man die regionale Ausprägung seines Dialekts für viele verschiedene Wörter angeben sollte. Habe dazu nur einen Artikel in der [Tiroler Tageszeitung](https://www.tt.com/artikel/15463803/letzte-runde-der-dialekt-umfrage-wie-wird-wo-in-tirol-gesprochen) gefunden, aber es gibt zum Beispiel den [Atlas Alltagssprache](https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/). Dr. Yvonne Kathrein von der UIBK hat zu Tiroler Dialekten auch viel publiziert, das dürfte aber vielleicht zu spezifisch sein.

Comment: '"Leg den Topf zum Trocknen auf den Herd" würde mich verwirren, weil er da ja auf seiner Unterseite auch stehen kann.' - als Süddeutscher würde ich den Topf bei dieser Anweisung wohl mit der Öffnung nach unten auf dem Herd platzieren (was zum Trocknen bzw. Abtropfen ja gar nicht so schlecht ist).

Answer (score 3):

So wie NXP5Z, der vor mir [eine Antwort zu dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/60965/1487) beigesteuert hat, bin auch ich aus Österreich, aber nicht aus dem Westen (NXP5Z gibt an aus Tirol zu sein) sondern aus dem Osten. (Ich wurde 1965 in Graz geboren und bin am nordöstlichen Rand dieser Stadt in einer ländlichen Gegend aufgewachsen mit Eltern und Verwandten aus der Oststeiermark. Von 1994 bis 1996 lebte ich in Leoben, 1997-2015 in Wien, seit 2016 in St. Pölten)

Da es gerade in der hier gestellten Frage erhebliche Unterschiede zwischen südbairischen und mittelbairischen Dialekten gibt, möchte ich im Folgenden etwas genauer ausführen, welche Dialekte in welchen Gegenden Österreichs gesprochen werden, und wie viele Sprecher zu welcher Gruppe gehören bevor ich im Anschluss auf die gestellte Frage eingehe.

---

### Dialekte im Westen Österreichs

**Vorarlberg**
In Vorarlberg werden alemannische Dialekte gesprochen (Hochalemannisch und Höchstalemannisch), somit gehört Vorarlberg zum selben Sprachgebiet wie der deutschsprachige Teil der Schweiz und das Schwabenland.

Vorarlberg hatte am 1.1.2020 genau 397.139 Einwohner.

Im Rest von Österreich werden bairische Dialekte gesprochen. Diese Dialektgruppe nennt man manchmal auch Bairisch-Österreichisch weil ein sehr großer Teil der Sprecher dieser Dialektgruppe in Österreich lebt. (Das deutsche Bundesland Bayern hat mit 13,1 Mio. Einwohnern zwar deutlich mehr Einwohner als Österreicher (8,9 Mio.), aber viele Bayern, z.B. die Franken, sprechen keinen bairischen Dialekt.)

Die bairischen Dialekte werden unterteilt in süd-, mittel- und nordbairische Dialekte, wobei die nordbairischen Dialekte nur in Deutschland verbreitet sind (nördlich von Ingolstadt, nördlich und westlich von Regensburg, östlich der Linie Bayreuth-Nürnberg, wobei Regensburg innerhalb dieses Gebiets liegt, die anderen genannten Städte aber außerhalb).

**Tirol und Kärnten**
In Südtirol (das in Italien liegt) und in Osttirol (zwischen Salzburg, Kärnten und Italien, ohne direkte Verbindung zu Nordtirol) werden, so wie auch in ganz Kärnten und der Weststeiermark (siehe unten: Gliederung der Steiermark) hauptsächlich südbairische Dialekte gesprochen, die man auch alpenbairische Dialekte nennt. Das trifft auch auf das Nordtiroler Oberland (westliche Hälfte von Nordtirol) und einen großen Teil des Unterlandes (das ist die östliche Hälfte von Nordtirol) zu. In den Bezirken Kufstein und Kitzbühel im Nordosten des Unterlandes, an Bayern und Salzburg angrenzend, findet man Mischformen aus süd- und mittelbairischen Dialekten, wobei das Mittelbairische umso mehr hervortritt, je weiter man nach Norden (Bayern) oder Osten (Salzburg) geht.
Ganz im Westen Nordtirols, zu Vorarlberg hin (Außerfern) findet man Mischformen aus südbairischen und alemannischen Dialekten.

Das Bundesland Tirol hatte am 1.1.2020 757.634 Einwohner, Kärnten 561.293. Zusammen also rund 1,32 Millionen. Zieht man die mittelbairisch sprechende Bevölkerung im Nordosten Tirols ab und zählt dafür die Einwohner der Weststeiermark dazu, dann wird die Anzahl der Österreicher, die südbairische Dialekte sprechen, ungefähr der Anzahl der Bewohner dieser beiden Bundesländer entsprechen. Man müsste auch noch die Bewohner des äußersten Westens des Salzburger Pinzgaues hinzuzählen, in diesem hochalpinen Gebiet leben aber nur rund 5.000 Menschen. Es bleibt also bei rund 1,3 Millionen südbairisch sprechenden Österreichern.

---

### Dialekte im Osten Österreichs

**Einschub: Geographische Gliederung der Steiermark**
Auch Teile des ehemaligen Herzogtums Steiermark liegen seit dem ersten Weltkrieg im Ausland. Das Herzogtum war in 3 Verwaltungszonen aufgeteilt: Obersteiermark in Norden (mit Leoben als Hauptstadt), in der Mitte die Mittelsteiermark (von Graz verwaltet), und im Süden die Untersteiermark (Hauptstadt: Marburg, heute Maribor). Die Untersteiermark fiel 1918 an das Königreich Jugoslawien und gehört heute zu Slowenien. Dort wurde von der Bevölkerung jedoch nie Deutsch gesprochen, sondern Slowenisch. Deutsch war dort in der Monarchie nur Verwaltungssprache.
Die von flachen Hügeln und kleineren Ebenen geprägte Mittelsteiermark ist flächenmäßig zwar um einiges kleiner als die gebirgige Obersteiermark, in ihr leben aber 73 % aller Steirer. Die Mittelsteiermark wird von Norden nach Süden von der Mur in zwei annähernd gleich große Hälften geteilt, die man Weststeiermark und Oststeiermark nennt. Ich beschreibe das deswegen so ausführlich, weil sich dadurch erklärt, warum nicht die große nach Westen reichende Auswölbung der Steiermark (die Bezirke Liezen, Murau und Murtal) »Weststeiermark« genannt wird (diese Bezirke gehören zur Obersteiermark) sondern die Bezirke Voitsberg und Deutschlandsberg ("eu" unbetont, Betonung auf "a": der deutsche Landsberg) sowie westliche Teile der Bezirke Graz Umgebung und Leibnitz. (Graz selbst wird weder zu West- noch zur Oststeiermark gezählt.)
**Ende des Einschubs**

Im Gebiet des ehemaligen Herzogtums Österreich (entspricht den heutigen Bundesländern Oberösterreich, Niederösterreich und Wien), des Fürsterzbistums Salzburg (heute das Bundsland Salzburg), der Ober- und Oststeiermark (siehe oben) und dem Burgenland (das 1921 nach einer Volksabstimmung von Ungarn zu Österreich gekommen ist) werden mittelbairische Dialekte gesprochen, die man auch donaubairische Dialekte nennt.

Die Mittelsteiermark (West- und Oststeiermark) ist ein Übergangsgebiet zwischen süd- und mittelbairischen Dialekten. Während die Mehrheit der Sprachforscher die Weststeiermark zum Gebiet der südbairischen Dialekte zählen, ist man sich bei der Oststeiermark nicht ganz einig. Da ich genau dort aufgewachsen bin (Vater aus der näheren Umgebung von Feldbach, Mutter aus Weiz, ich in Graz geboren) und der dort gesprochene Dialekt meine eigentliche Muttersprache ist, wage ich zu behaupten, dass die Oststeiermark - trotz einiger südbairischer Elemente - zum mittelbairischen Sprachgebiet zu zählen ist.

So viele Österreicher leben in Bundesländern, in denen mittelbairische Dialekte vorherrschen (Zahlen vom 1.1.2020):

- Wien: 1.911.191
- Niederösterreich: 1.684.287
- Oberösterreich: 1.490.279
- Steiermark: 1.246.395
- Salzburg: 558.410
- Burgenland: 294.436

In Summe: 7.184.998 also rund 7,2 Millionen Menschen. Da müsste man nun wieder die Weststeirer abziehen und Einwohner von Kufstein und Kitzbühel dazuzählen, aber wie bereits argumentiert wird das insgesamt das Endergebnis kaum verändern.

---

### Alle drei Dialektgruppen Österreichs

- Hoch- und Höchstalemannisch: ca. 0,4 Millionen Sprecher = 4,5 % aller Österreicher
- Südbairisch: ca. 1,3 Millionen Sprecher = 14,8 % aller Österreicher
- Mittelbairisch: ca. 7,2 Millionen Sprecher = 80,7 % aller Österreicher

---

### Beantwortung der eigentlichen Frage

In Licht der oben erläuterten Zahlen muss man die Aussage von NXP5Z, wonach kein Österreicher den Satz

> Er gibt den Topf auf den Herd.

sagen würde, sehr stark anzweifeln. Wenn ich ausdrücken wollte, dass ein Topf auf einem Herd platziert wird, würde ich genau diesen Satz (und somit das Verb *geben*) verwenden, und vermutlich würden rund 7,2 Millionen mittelbairisch sprechende Österreicher, also 80 % der Gesamtbevölkerung, das ebenfalls tun.

**Deckel auf Topf**

Ich, Sprecher einer Mischung verschiedener österreichischer mittelbairischer Dialekte, würde hochdeutsch diesen Satz formulieren:

> Erich **gibt** den Deckel auf den Topf.

Von den anderen vorgeschlagenen Varianten klingt nur diese für mich korrekt:

> Erich **legt** den Deckel auf den Topf.

Falsch klingen für mich diese Varianten:

> Erich **setzt** den Deckel auf den Topf.
> Erich **stellt** den Deckel auf den Topf.
> Erich **macht** den Deckel auf den Topf.
> Erich **tut** den Deckel auf den Topf.

**Topf auf Herd**

Bevorzugt:

> Anna **stellt** den Topf auf den Herd.

Auch als korrekt wahrgenommen:

> Anna **gibt** den Topf auf den Herd.

Empfinde ich als falsch:

> Anna **setzt** den Topf auf den Herd.
> Anna **legt** den Topf auf den Herd.
> Anna **macht** den Topf auf den Herd.
> Anna **tut** den Topf auf den Herd.

Wenn man mir sagt, jemand habe einen Topf irgendwo hingelegt, dann würde ich annehmen, dass der Topf sich dann in Seitenlage befindet, also dass er weder mit seiner Unterseite auf dem Boden aufliegt, noch kopfüber (mit der Öffnung nach unten) orientiert ist, sondern mit der Unterseite im ungefähr rechten Winkel zur Auflagefläche.

**Wasser aufsetzen, Wasser aufstellen**

Ich weiß nicht, ob die im Folgenden beschriebene Formulierung im ganzen mittelbairischen Sprachraum geläufig ist, oder vielleicht sogar darüber hinaus, aber ich kenne sie aus der Steiermark und habe sie auch in Wien gehört:

> Ich habe schon das Wasser für den Tee aufgestellt/aufgesetzt.

Mit *»Wasser aufstellen«* und dem gleichbedeutenden *»Wasser aufsetzen«* ist nämlich gemeint, dass man einen Topf mit Wasser füllt, ihn auf den Herd stellt und den Herd einschaltet um das Wasser zum Kochen zu bringen.

Man kann allerdings auch z.B. Erdäpfel, Nudeln usw. aufstellen/aufsetzen. Damit ist gemeint, dass sich diese Lebensmittel zusammen mit Wasser im Topf befinden, sonst wie zuvor beschrieben.

**Buch ins Regal**

Das wurde zwar nicht konkret abgefragt, scheint mir aber doch im Sinn der gestellten Frage zu sein.

Von mir als korrekt empfundene Varianten:

- Kurt **stellt** das Buch ins Regal.
  Das Buch ruht mit der Unterkante der beiden Buchdeckel und der Unterkante des Rückens auf einem Regalbrett, links und rechts davon befinden sich möglicherweise gleich orientierte Bücher.
- Kurt **gibt** das Buch ins Regal.
  Wird von mir gleich verstanden wie *stellen.*
- Kurt **legt** das Buch ins Regal.
  Das Buch berührt mit der ganzen Fläche eines der beiden Buchdeckel seine Unterlage (entweder das Regalbrett oder ein anderes ebenfalls liegendes Buch).

Von mir als falsch empfunden:

- Kurt **setzt** das Buch ins Regal.
- Kurt **macht** das Buch ins Regal.
- Kurt **tut** das Buch ins Regal.

**Buch auf den Tisch**

Für stellen, legen, setzen, machen und tun gilt dasselbe wie für die Variante wo das Regal das Ziel war. (Mit dem Unterschied, dass ich von einem Buch, das jemand auf den Tisch stellt, nicht erwarte, dass es dort zwischen anderen Büchern, sondern eher alleine steht.)

Dieser Satz ist aber anders:

> Magda **gibt** das Buch auf den Tisch.

Diesen Satz halte ich zwar nicht für prinzipiell falsch, würde ihn aber trotzdem nicht verwenden. Wenn ich diesen Satz höre, glaube ich auch nicht, dass das Buch dann auf den Tisch steht, sondern dass es dort liegt.

Comment: Leider kann man keine Privatnachrichten schreiben. Es ist absolut Ihre Entscheidung, aber ich persönlich würde nicht so viele konkrete Details zu meiner Person im Internet posten, vor allem nicht auf Seiten mit extrem hohem Traffic wie stackexchange.

Comment: @NXP5Z: Völlig richtig: Das ist meine Entscheidung und ich bin durchaus in der Lage selbst zu entscheiden, welche persönlichen Informationen ich öffentlich bekanntgebe und welche nicht.